# How can I get my program to automatically perform a carriage return when string value superseeds the screen size?

Tags: swift, uilabel, carriage-return

I am making a quiz game that displays questions fetched from parse. I create the label programmatically, but stumble upon some issues when the string value is too long. Is there a way to make the label automatically print on a new line when it goes beyond the screen width?

Comment: Without going into details: Auto Layout is the preferred approach. See Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: I figured this out. I decided to make the frame a bit bigger and add in lines using the label.numberOfLines function. Now it returns perfectly. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I decided to make the frame a bit bigger and add in lines using the label.numberOfLines function. Now it returns perfectly.